# How to stream flv file (encoded by gstreamer flvmux and it contains h264 video with aac audio) to rtmp server without decoding it ?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a dynamic pipeline (written in c code) which imitates following static pipeline and generates flv video:

```
gst-launch-1.0  flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! queue ! filesink sync=true location="cam.flv" rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.0.157:7001/yamahamg10xu.sdp" caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MPA, payload=(int)96" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=1000 ! rtpmpadepay !  mpegaudioparse ! queue ! mad ! audioconvert ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=64000 ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! queue ! mux. rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:fallenjiva@192.168.0.161:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=1000 ! rtph264depay ! shift delay=550000 running-time=true ! queue ! mux.
```

This dynamic pipeline works fine and generates a video (lets call it pipeline-1)

Now i have another static pipeline (pipeline-2) which runs and broadcast it to rtmp server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=cam.flv ! decodebin name=demux ! queue ! x264enc pass=pass1 threads=0 bitrate=900 tune=zerolatency ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://xxxxxxxxx live=1' demux. ! queue ! progressreport ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! audioresample ! faac bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! mux.
```

2nd pipeline (above) also works fine and gives no error but it is decoding/encoding an already encoded video which is optmized for transmission.

My question is for 2nd pipeline. 2nd pipeline is taking cam.flv as input which is already h264/aac encoded in flv format. I want to stream it without decoding/re-encoding using gstreamer.

How do I do it ? I knew that I can do it in ffmpeg (using  -acodec copy and -vcodec copy options )but I don't use ffmpeg . I want to use gstreamer to do that same functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this but pipeline is not broadcasting anything and it is exiting very fast (<30sec).

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=live_cam.flv ! queue ! flvdemux name=demuxer ! queue ! aacparse ! muxer. demuxer. ! queue ! h264parse ! flvmux name=muxer streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location='rtmp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX live=1'
```

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.066118003  8316      0x2504d90 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3064:gst_base_sink_default_event: stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock